# What is the proper way to use marginfix in memoir?

Tags: memoir, marginnote, sidenotes

My question is about the proper use of marginfix in memoir so that marginal material appears where the documentation of memoir says it should appear.

I use option `twoside` and `\marginparmargin{right}` in memoir to place marginal material on the right margin for all pages, as explained in memman, p239. However, when I add `\usepackage[side,ragged,flushmargin,multiple]{footmisc}` to the code, marginal material is placed on the left margin if the page is even numbered (see MWE below). The problem is fixed by changing to `oneside` in memoir. This works but contradicts the explanation of `\marginparmargin` in memoir's documentation, as well as the documentation of marginfix that says no known conflict exists with memoir. Is there another "proper" way to use marginfix with memoir?

```
\documentclass[10pt,twoside]{memoir}
\usepackage{lipsum} 
\usepackage[side,ragged,flushmargin,multiple]{footmisc} 
\usepackage{marginfix} 
\settypeblocksize{8in}{4.5in}{*}
\setlrmargins{0.7in}{*}{*}
\setmarginnotes{17pt}{150pt}{\onelineskip}  
\marginparmargin{right} 
\checkandfixthelayout
\setlength{\evensidemargin}{\oddsidemargin} 
\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-4]
Place footnote here\footnote{\lipsum[5]}

\lipsum[5-8]
Place footnote here\footnote{\lipsum[9]}

\end{document}
```

Comment: (1) welcome, (2) I don't use footmisc, but I'm assuming that when use you use footmisc with the side option it may have overwritten the memoir adjustment to marginpar thus setting those will not have any effect. Why do you need footmisc and marginfix at all?

Comment: (1) thanks! (2) footmisc places footnotes on the side (I am trying to emulate tufte-book), and marginfix does a nice job with the vertical alignment of material in the margin. If you remove marginfix from the sample I sent, you may notice that some footnotes run below the last line of the page. The problem is with marginfix, not footmisc. The problem persists if you remove footmisc but you will have to use a \marginpar to see it since footnotes will not be in the margin any more.

Comment: `marginfix` changes `\@addmarginpar` and thus the memoir changes to `\@addmarginpar` are gone, those `memoir` changes include which margin it goes to.

Answer (score 1):

Following from @dalief's comment, removing the `marginfix` package gives you what you are after as far as I understand it. Further, if you also remove the `footmisc` package and add the `memoir` command`\footnotesinmargin` to your preamble you also get what you are after.

Comment: Peter, I can see what he means. Remove `footmisc`, add `\footnotesinmargin`, then see the bottom placement of the first note in the margin. So `marginfix` seems to work just fine, it is just the `footmisc` stuff that does something incompatible. Hmm, just noticed that `marginfix` apparently also messes the left/right` ...

Comment: If there is equivalent functionality in memoir to replace marginfix, I will gladly use it. I like how marginfix adjusts side material vertically so it does not run below the bottom of the text.

Comment: @Themis It seems that `marginfix` does affect `memoir`. Perhaps the maintainers can sort this out between them. (It would be nice if `memoir` was tweaked to stop bottom overflow, but that could lead to top overflow:-) I can see it getting very complicated. I suppose the alternative is to use fewer/shorter side footnotes.

Comment: @Peter Thanks for looking into it. It feels good to be talking to the developer of such a great system, `memoir` has been my default document class for quite a while.